# .NET CF 3.5 Forms talking to sync-only network device

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, asynchronous, compact-framework

Ok, time for me to ask my first question on here...

I have created a number of Views (CF 3.5 User Controls, using OpenNETCF.IoC and resco controls) and a navigation controller for them.

I have also created an abstraction layer ("driver") for a quite curious proprietary network device. Commands can only be executed synchronously on the device, but I use a reader thread to listen to messages (that may come at any time, or in response to a synchronous command) from the device. These messages can be dispatched in events or queued up.

Sort of like this, in the "driver" interface:

`public Response ExecuteCommand(Command command);` <= this is the synchronous call. Some commands may run for minutes.

`public event DeviceMessageReceivedEvent;` <= if this is subscribed, incoming messages that are not a direct reply to a call to the above method will be dispatched in the event args. this will be called from the reader thread.

`public Queue DeviceMessages;` <= if the event is not subscribed, such messages go here.

There is also a convenience application facade but it is basically just a fancy wrapper for the ExecuteCommand call, so I will omit it here.

THE QUESTION:

How would i best wire up data received in Events and/or the Queue to the views, and how would i best implement an asynchronous wrapper over the ExecuteCommand method - which, just to reiterate, has to run synchronously due to limitations in the device's networking protocol (Yes, it really is pretty terrible.)

After reading up quite a bit on asynchronous programming with .NET CF 3.5 WinForms i am at a loss how to proceed. In a first demo, i was using DataBindings a lot but this has lead to problems with there being no apparent way to use Control.Invoke when required. I also weaseled my way around the asychronous Execute problem by just executing all commands synchronously with the UI thread and polling for messages on the queue using an anonymous thread instead of using the event. This i would very much like to change for obvious reasons.

CF does not offer BeginInvoke and EndInvoke, but i suppose those would be simple enough to re-implement?

Should I create a static view-centric model? Will that even simplify matters?

Should I create an extra "inbetween" thread to handle state transfer between model/view and driver? Will that even simplify matters?

...?

I guess I am looking for some brainstorming on general design principles here. I have never been much of a UI person, mostly been doing systems programming, and never more .NET than i could avoid. The concepts of asynchronous programming are quite clear, just not how to apply them in this context.

So.. Any input is appreciated, also book recommendations etc...

Answer (score 1):

The sounds way, way, way too much like a project I'm currently working on.  I have hardware that I can send only one command at a time through.  Those commands may time out, or may just wait until the receiver wakes.  Commands come in as replies, or as unsolicited data messages.

What I did was to actually create a few layers with some names I'm just making up now

**Lowest layer - communications bus:**

- knows how to send and receive.
- knows how to parse incoming data into "frames" but nothing more (it knows the delimiter and checksum). This is actually done in a buffering thread in the OpenNETCF.IO serial library.
- puts parsed frames into a queue to minimize receiver thread busy state
- Has a worker thread that watches the Rx queue and dispatches frames
- Exposes a simple "send" interface (sending is handled in the layer above)

**Next Layer - API (?) layer**

Device Monitor

- Knows what end devices exist
- knows when I last heard from them
- receives frames from the communication bus and puts them in a queue (so as to not block the receiver)
- knows how to better parse frames
- raises message-specific events
- sends messages (from retrieved from the message handler) when a node comes on line
- has two worker threads:

  - TxThread handles the "one and only one outgoing message" issue by pulling from a que
    Message handler
  - RxThread receives watches incoming frame queue, parses and dispatches those messages

Message Manager

- Knows what messages need to go to what devices
- Knows state of each message (not sent, waiting response, timed out, etc)
- Allows filtering of "to send", "timed out" etc. items

**Service Layer**

- consumes and abstracts the API layer
- Exposes objects and events to applications (direct and via REST)
- Does data aggregation (averages, battery monitoring, etc)
- Contains business rules/logic

The point here is that I didn't explicitly implement any async APIs, though almost everything in the library is asynchronous in behavior.  The UI simply looks for events (INotifyPropertyChanged abounds) for incoming stuff.  For outgoing, it does something like "Request to set pin 1 high", which is non-blocking.  The Service layer does some checking to validate the action actually occurred on the remote end, but the UI simply looks at the "pin state" property and when it actually changes to high (as verified in the service layer), it updates.

Comment: There are definitely some similiarities there. I was even considering creating something much like your TxThread today. Thank you for your input. Also, if you are the ctacke i think you are, your writings have already been extremely valueable to me. Thank you for that.

Comment: small update: i am actively working on this and will eventually "answer" my own question properly for other peoples benefit. from your abstract description i guess you're doing something like modbus/tcp. trust me, this is much worse, the protocol is proprietary and broken in all kinds of ways and places. a lot of time goes into this and other areas so i can't devote much of it to coming up with good architechture. a pattern derived from what you posted would make sense but i will need to do explicit async stuff. i have just jotted down some pseudocode and will post again tomorrow after work.

Comment: I'm doing zigbee at this point, but yes, I've done modbus in the past.  If what you're working on is worse, then you have my sympathy.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of updates, i am very busy. However, just found this extremely helpful article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S1 Material like that is invaluable if you're relatively new to .NET threading...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with a crapload of specific IAsyncResult Begin/End calls, and other fun stuff resulting in a solution that is not really pretty or well suited for a single core single pipeline CPU. But since then i have revisited the problem in a new project. Here, i created a simple wrapper that allows me to fire and forget asynchronous calls in CF with ease. It may not be perfect but it does an excellent job at what i need it to do.

Note, that this is only for the UI stuff.

The new architecture now comprises of a generic connection layer (serial and tcp through a common interface), a device specific API layer (several devices that have little in common on this level), a device specific presentation controller, a generic presentation model (tuns out they actually have a lot in common once abstracted), and on top of that the view, which is controlled indirectly through the presentation model by the presentation controllers. The view is not exactly the same for all devices (device specific functionality) but the presentation controller controls what is visible/loaded in the view.

But without further ado,

Invocation example:

```
        AsyncCallback callback = delegate(IAsyncResult result)
                                     {
                                         IView2MainContainer.StopWaiting();
                                         try
                                         {
                                             AsyncHelper.EndInvoke(result);
                                         }
                                         catch (Exception ex)
                                         {
                                             RescoMessageBoxHelper.ShowOK(
                                                 string.Format(StringResources.Message_FirmwareUpdateError,
                                                               ex.Message), MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                                             return;
                                         }
                                         RescoMessageBoxHelper.ShowOK(StringResources.Message_FirmwareUpdateComplete, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                                     };

        AsyncHelper.BeginInvoke(
            callback,
            delegate
                {
                    IView2MainContainer.StartWaiting(StringResources.Message_WaitFirmwareUpdate);
                    presenterModel.CurrentDevice.UpdatePrinterFirmware(firmwareDataBuffer);
                }
            );
```

The implementation:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Allen.IView2.Common
{
  public static class AsyncHelper
  {
    private static readonly object resultsLock = new object();
    private static volatile List<AsyncResultImpl> results = new List<AsyncResultImpl>();

    public static void EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (!(result is AsyncResultImpl))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The async result was of an unknown type.");

        lock (resultsLock)
        {
            if (!results.Contains((AsyncResultImpl) result))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The async result was unknown");
            }
            results.Remove((AsyncResultImpl) result);
        }
        ((AsyncResultImpl) result).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        Exception ex = ((AsyncResultImpl) result).Exception;
        ((AsyncResultImpl) result).Dispose();

        if (ex != null)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static void BeginInvoke(AsyncCallback callback, Action action)
    {
        var result = new AsyncResultImpl(callback, null);

        lock (resultsLock)
        {
            results.Add(result);
        }

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
                                         {
                                             try
                                             {
                                                 action.Invoke();
                                             }
                                             catch (Exception ex)
                                             {
                                                 result.Complete(ex);
                                                 return;
                                             }
                                             result.Complete();
                                         });
    }
}
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Allen.IView2.Common
{
  public class AsyncResultImpl : IAsyncResult, IDisposable
  {
    private AsyncCallback callback;
    private Exception exception;
    private object state;
    private ManualResetEvent waitHandle;

    public AsyncResultImpl(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.state = state;
        waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public ManualResetEvent AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { return waitHandle; }
    }

    public Exception Exception
    {
        get { return exception; }
    }

    public object AsyncState
    {
        get { return state; }
    }

    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle
    {
        get { return AsyncWaitHandle; }
    }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return waitHandle.WaitOne(0, false); }
    }

    public void Dispose() // lazy dispose
    {
        if (null != waitHandle)
        {
            waitHandle.Close();
            waitHandle = null;
            state = null;
            callback = null;
        }
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        Complete(null);
    }

    public void Complete(Exception exception)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
        waitHandle.Set();
        if (null != callback)
            if (callback.GetInvocationList().Length > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A callback must not be multicast.");
        if (null != callback)
        {
            try
            {
                callback(this);
            }
            catch
            {
// nom nom
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```